# CSS files not loading in drf-yasg

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, swagger, mime-types, drf-yasg

I have integrated swagger in django project using drf-yasg. Everything works fine on localhost but when deployed on development , swagger-ui css and js are not loading in browser.
It gives the following error:

**Refused to apply style from '/static/drf-yasg/swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.**

I have set following values in settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: have u defined static file folder in django?

Comment: it is created by running python manage.py collectstatic command

Comment: Did you make the required changes to `settings.py` and `urls.py`? See [the docs](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/readme.html#quickstart)